# How to programatically access webpages(Google Adsense) or emails,chats?

Tags: java, web-services, chat, adsense

I want to process webpages(Google Adsense) or emails,chats.For that i need to to access the webpages(Google Adsense) or emails,chats programatically.Is there any Api in java or webservices available by which we can access those(Google Adsense,Microsoft AdCenter,Emails,Chats)?

Comment: Why do you want that? What have you tried so far? Please give some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For google adsence api - [link](https://developers.google.com/adsense/)

For google chat api - [link](https://developers.google.com/talk/)

Microsoft AdCenter api - [link](http://advertising.microsoft.com/small-business/search-advertising/adcenter-api)

for Email - you can write email client on basis of supported protocol

Answer (score 1):

The question is very tricky. If it is just the web page response that you want to get, then you can use [Apache's HTTPClient API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)

If you want to individually access the services of these Website, then you have to see if such websites exposes their services through SOAP or REST